# how to iterate over files with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to iterate over files in a folder using powershell script;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { <# do what you need to do #> }
```

or shorter:

```
gci | % { <# ... #> }
```

or if you want an explicit looping construct:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem) {
    # ...
}
```

Note however, that `foreach` will only run once all output from `Get-ChildItem` is collected. In my opinion most Powershell code should use the pipeline as much as possible.

Comment: If you have a large number of files, [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles. It requires .NET 4+. But it doesn't wait until it iterates over all files. Which is a problem if you have thousands within a directory. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970692/powershell-io-directory-find-file-types-in-all-subdirectories

Comment: @TamusJRoyce: Get-ChildItem should stream as well. As opposed to Directory.GetFiles, of course, which returns an array.