# Powershell - IO.Directory - Find file types in all subdirectories

Tags: .net, powershell

I ran across this code in another post that almost does what I need, but can't figure out how to modify it to look for specific file types, i.e. *.bak, *.txt, etc.  I'm using Powershell with [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] because, like others have stated, using Get-ChildItem is too slow across the network.  I thought it would just be something like $fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("C:\", "*.bak"), but it still returns every file in every directory. --PS/.NET newbie

```
try
{
       $fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("C:\")
       [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$directInf = New-Object IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\")
       $folders = $directInf.GetDirectories()
}
catch [Exception]
{
       $_.Exception.Message
       $folders = @()
 }

foreach($fileName in $fileEntries) 
{

      #[Console]::WriteLine($fileName); 

}

Remove-Variable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name fileEntries 

foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    recurse("C:\" + $folder + "\")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will loop through each extension searching for all files in the root and sub-directories. Ensure you have the correct privileges on all the directories especially when you're running from C:\ as the root.

```
$Extensions = @(".bak",".csv",".txt")

Foreach ( $Extension in $Extensions )
{
   [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles("C:\","*$Extension","AllDirectories")
}
```

This method will only work with Powershell running .Net 4.0 or higher.
To check and update the version of .Net:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4971
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

The CLRVersion value is the .net version.

Update the config file as follows:

```
$Config = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
"@

$Config > $PSHOME\Powershell.exe.config
```

Restart the Powershell session and verify the CLRVersion value in the $PSVersionTable variable.

Comment: Thanks.  Do I have a syntax issue with Powershell?  I get "Method invocation failed because [systemRuntimeType] doesn't contain a method named 'EnumerateDirectories' error.

Comment: I had the same error with Powrshell 2.0 but it works on Powershell 3.0

Comment: Bummer.  I don't have the ability to install 3.0 yet.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the EnumerateFiles method?  I also tried GetFiles with [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories, but ran into the "Access Denied" error against the "System Volume Information" directory.

Comment: If you're going to do this at the root of the C:\ driver  then you will need to have full access to all the directories otherwise you're bound to get access denied.
GetFiles and EnumerateFiles carry out the same function except EnumerateFiles is faster as it works on the files in order, whereas GetFiles returns the complete list of files first, then starts work on them.

To use EnumerateFiles you can stick to Powershell 2.0, but you need to modify the Powershell config file to use .Net 4.0 or higher.

Comment: I created a powershell.exe.config and powershell_ise.exe.config file for .NET 4.0 but still run into Method invocation errors. Not sure if I set it up wrong.  For the "Access Denied" error, I tried a filter like "| where {$_.name -ne "System Volume Information"}".  The folder exists on every drive I'm scanning and prohibits administrator access.  I dont' want to modify some attribute of it on 50+ servers to "fix" it.  I'll have to find a way to get around it with catch [Exception], etc.

Comment: The original posted code recurses through all subfolders without issue, but finds *all* files instead of specifc ones.  I figured there was somewhere inside one of those loops or ::GetFiles that I could add the filter for file type.

Comment: To verify that the config changes have taken effect, check the $PSVersionTable variable, this has a "CLRVersion" and the value should switch to 4.xxxx if the configurations have been correctly applied.

The where filter will not work because as I explained earlier, GetFiles will retrieve the whole list of files before carrying out the operation on the files, so it's going to always fail in that case.

Comment: Please post the solution if you've found it as it could be helpful to others, I will update my answer with the steps to set the .Net version.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the info.  Looks like I may have done something incorrectly with the config file(s).  The CLRVersion Value still shows 2.0.50727.3643.  Haven't found the solution yet, but will post as soon as I do.  I think the enumeratefiles might be it if the method works after fixing the .NET version.

Comment: Sorry for the hassle, but I get an error with Powershell after updating the config file.  "The system cannot execute the specified program" or (ISE):  "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.  Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

Comment: OK, I'm guessing it's probably not a syntax issue but yet another permissions-type of roadblock with corp policy.  ugh.

Comment: I saved a config file on my pc successfully, so now I have a little work to do.  Hopefully, I'll be able to post a solution soon.

Comment: The ::EnumerateFiles method works now, but is there a way to avoid the same "Access Denied" error I ran into using ::GetFiles?  Also, how would I capture/display only the filename vs. the entire path+filename?  Using $file.fullname or $file.name shows the process running/scrolling but no value is displayed for each row.

Comment: have a look at this discussion, it has a solution to avoid the Access Denied error from stopping the recursion, it's a bit complex though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293/access-to-the-path-is-denied-when-using-directory-getfiles

To return the filename only you're going to have to do a bit of string manipulation as the results returned are strings, not file objects.

Comment: This retrieves files and catches the exception in a one-line error message, but now it looks like I face another problem of not being able to filter by date because [IO.DirectoryInfo], NOT [IO.Directory], has the FileObject properties like .CreationTime?  Seriously, already, who wrote this stuff, Howdy Doody?  :)

Comment: try { $path = "\\$myserver\$\($drive.replace(':','$'))"
      $files = [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path, "*.bak", "AllDirectories")
  foreach($file in $files)
    { # do processing }
    }
catch [UnauthorizedAccessException]
  { write-host $_.Exception.Message}

Comment: Using [IO.DirectoryInfo].$dir = New-Object IO.DirectoryInfo($path)
 $files = $dir.EnumerateFiles($path, "*.bak", "AllDirectories") returns an error:
Property 'Documents and Settings' cannot be found on this object'

Can someone tell me if/where I'm entering something incorrectly?

Comment: I'm beset with errors when trying to use IO.DirectoryInfo.  I'm also trying New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($file) in my foreach($file in $files) iteration, but that is producing an error, too:  "New-Object : Constructor not found.  Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.IO.FileInfo."  I just need a way using IO.Directory + something else or IO.DirectoryInfo to sort/filter against the file date.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it using [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles and IO.FileInfo.  The last thing I'd like to do is exclude system or hidden files - can that be done just by comparing some attribute in the FileInfo object, i.e. $file.System -ne "true" or "0"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple PowerShell script to move many files from a directory into a structured directory by year, month and day.  This is very fast, I had over 500K files.

```
$listofFiles =   [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles("D:\LotsOfFiles","*.*","TopDirectoryOnly")

$listofFiles |% {
   $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($_)    
   $date = Get-Date ($file.CreationTime)
   $filepath = ("{0}\{1:00}\{2:00}-{3}\{4:00}\" -f "D:\LotsOfFiles", $date.year, 
   $date.month, $date.toString("MMM"), $date.day)
   Write-Output ("Move: {0} to {1}" -f $file.Fullname, $filepath)

   if (! (Test-Path $filepath)) {       
      new-item -type Directory -path $filepath      
   }

   move-item $file $filepath
}
```

This probably can be improved but it works.

Comment: I know I'm asking this question pretty late, I'm stuck with the same situation and used the above code.  Any chance you remember how long it took to move all these files?

Comment: Looks cool. For PS < 7.0, it should be faster by changing ``$listofFiles | % {`` to ``foreach ( $item in $listofFiles) {``. Also, New-Object is typically slow. It should be faster to do ``$file = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($item)``. Also is the test-path if-block necessary?

Answer (score -1):

This worked after creating a config file to use the .NET 4.0 Framework:

```
try{
    $path = "\\$Server\$($drive.replace(':','$'))"
    foreach ($filepath in [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path,"*.bak","AllDirectories"))
       {
          $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($filepath)
          write-host $file
          # insert file into database table
       }
  }
catch [UnauthorizedAccessException]
  {
     $exception = $_.Exception.Message #I don't need to write/insert exception
  }
```