# Loop through subfolders in powershell

Tags: xml, csv, powershell

Hi there I am quite new to Powershell however I have managed to write this script which does exactly what I want however there are multiple folders that I must iterate through and wondering if it is at all possible as I cannot seem to find a solution.

```
cd E:\Project_Data\Data_part1
$files = Get-ChildItem "E:\Project_Data\Data_part1\"*.xml


$MasterArray = @()
$MasterArray = "" | Select Entries
$ConcatEntries = @()
foreach ($file in $files)
{

$MasterArray.Entries += -Join "|$|"

[xml]$XMLfile = gc $file 


$Entries = $XMLfile.InsuranceClaim.InfoFromVet.AnimalClinicalHistory.Entry
$ConcatEntries = @()
foreach ($Entry in $Entries)
{
$ConcatEntries += "E:\Project_Data\Data_part1\"+$file + "|^|" + $Entry.Date
 + "|^|" + $Entry.Time + "|^|" + $Entry.EnteredBy + "|^|" +  $Entry.TextEntry
}

$MasterArray.Entries += $ConcatEntries -Join "|$|"

}

$MasterArray | Export-Csv -NoType "C:\Desktop\out.csv"
```

As you can probably see it takes one node of an inputted xml file and outputs a single repeating node to a csv file. I am hoping to implement something like the following however am not sure how to define the $folders variable. Sorry if this is a bit long winded and thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

```
 foreach($folder in $folders)
 {
 cd $folder
 $files = Get-ChildItem $folder*.xml


 $MasterArray = @()
 $MasterArray = "" | Select Entries
 $ConcatEntries = @()
 foreach ($file in $files)
 {

 $MasterArray.Entries += -Join "|$|"

 [xml]$XMLfile = gc $file 


 $Entries = $XMLfile.InsuranceClaim.InfoFromVet.AnimalClinicalHistory.Entry
 $ConcatEntries = @()
 foreach ($Entry in $Entries)
 {
$ConcatEntries += $folder + $file + "|^|" + $Entry.Date + "|^|" + 
$Entry.Time + "|^|" + $Entry.EnteredBy + "|^|" +  $Entry.TextEntry
 }

 $MasterArray.Entries += $ConcatEntries -Join "|$|"

 $MasterArray | Export-Csv -NoType $folder+"\"+$file+"out.csv"
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could defined the $folders variable by using the following
PowerShell 3.0+:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Project_Data -Directory -Recurse
```

PowerShell 2.0:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Project_Data -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Mode -Match "d"}
```

Comment: The way its set up the directory E:\Project_Data\ contains lots of different data folders and within each of these around 1000 xml files, so basically I am looking for a way to not have to edit the path each time I want to access a new folder.

Comment: "gci E:\Project_Data -Directory -Recurse"
this would get all of the directories and subdirectories in the project_data folder. You could then use that foreach loop to grab the xml files.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I have tried to run both of those snippets however I get the error that a parameter can not be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'... could you please elaborate on how to use this sorry I am quite new to powershell

Comment: Sorry about that, the "-Directory" switch works in PowerShell 4.0. You can use this in place of it for Powershell 2.0: "gci E:\Project_Data -Recurse | where {$_.Mode -Match 'd'}"

Comment: Hi Hive I have managed to get the script working using the method you mentioned in the last comment thanks very much for the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970692/powershell-io-directory-find-file-types-in-all-subdirectories) might have what you need..

```
$folders = [IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("C:\temp","*","AllDirectories")
```

Then..

```
 Foreach ($fldr in $folders) {do some stuff}
```

?

Comment: Could not get this method to work for me it would not take in the full directory like I needed, however I have managed to now get the script working using Hive's suggestion thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same directory, just add -recurse to the Get-ChildItem command, and instead of specifying the wildcard in the path, use the -Filter switch.

Otherwise, use something like:

```
$files+= C:\someotherfolder\*.xml
```

Comment: Hi Chris I have the -recurse method the problem with it is once it gets down to using the file because the powershell directory is not set to the absolute path powershell then cannot find the file

Answer (score 0):

An option that you have which I think will assist you is also adding in the variable for the directory, so you will want to do the following, to replace your `$Files` declaration

```
function get-XMLfromFile{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
    (
    [string]$Subfolder
    )
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Project_Data\$Subfolder\*.xml" -Recurse
```

now the last line is only what I got from the above answer that you replied to, and don't forget to add another `}` to the end and this will make your script a function. I can work on making it let you choose what folder to get if this is going to put you in a direction you want to go, but it will basically allow you to change the subfolder you are searching and you won't have to change the script only the arguments that you pass it.

Comment: Hi Luke I could not seem to get this method to work possibly due to my lack of knowledge of the Powershell syntax however I have managed to get the script working using Hive's method, Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3456401 right this is more of an addition to his method, I saw your comment about needing to be able to search more than one folder. this will allow you to search any sub-folder in the `project-data` folder and only search that folder, but if this is something that you want to do it might require some additional changes to my code; I would just need to know some specifics so I could do that.