# How can I run a command 'x' number of times, in batch file or PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command

I've got a maintenance script that is generating `.sql` files with some SQL script in there.

When the file size reaches a limit, I close the file and create a new one, dumping the data into the 2nd file.

I have no idea how many files will be generated (it's based upon the amount of data at the current time). So far it looks like it's about 100 files or so.

So, is there a nice way I can say

- Get all the files that end with `.sql` from a target directory.
- now run this command for each one.

The command I run in the Command window on my SQL Server is this:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -d SomeDBTenant -U someUser -P somePassword -I -i c:\temp\SqlScript_1.sql
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to iterate over files with powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605522/how-to-iterate-over-files-with-powershell)

Comment: I guess you do not really mean "DOS" but Windows command prompt, right? Please consider to adapt the question title accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to get all `.sql` files (add `-recurse`if you want to do it recursively) and run sqlcmd for each of them:

```
$sqlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test' -Filter '*.sql' # you can do it recurse with -r
$sqlFiles | foreach { sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -d SomeDBTenant -U someUser -P somePassword -I -i $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Windows command prompt you can use `for` to walk through all files that match (a) certain pattern(s) in a directory or a directory tree, like:

```
rem remove the `/R` switch if you don't want to loop recursively
for /R %%F in (*.sql) do (
  REM replace `%%~F` by `%%~fF` to pass the file's full path to the command
  sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -d SomeDBTenant -U someUser -P somePassword -I -i "%%~F"
)
```

**Note:**
This only works when `sqlcmd` does *not* create/rename/delete any `*.sql` files in the enumerated directory. In addition, if the `/R` option is used, `sqlcmd` must *not* modify the enumerated directory tree.

Comment: If the `sqlcmd` is creating .sql files then the for command can re-process some .sql files a second time etc.  Using the `for /f` form of the for command with dir will avoid this.

Comment: Good point, @foxidrive! I tried that once with a non-recursive `for`, it seems that `for` enumerates the directory content once; however, I did not try this with `/R` -- I'll do that the next days and correct my code in case...

Comment: That's a nice answer for the command prompt. BTW @foxidrive the `sqlcmd` executable is NOT creating the `.sql` files. something -else- does that ... `sqlcmd` just parses/reads the scripts (and executes them).

Comment: @Pure.Krome  What filetype is your sqlcmd creating ?

Comment: It's _not_ creating anything. `sqlcmd.exe` comes with Sql Server for doing cli stuff. I have a different app that creates files (that end with `.sql`) and use those with sqlcmd.

Comment: @foxidrive, I decided to post a question concerning enumeration of directories whose contents change during that, using `for` -- see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31975093/5047996)...

Comment: @aschipfl  Thanks for your message.  Aacini is a smart fellow.